# SSIS: use array as data source from data flow

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

I have to read thousands of path and files from the hard disk. I have used a foreach loop container to read them, but it takes hours.
I was thinking about to read the files from a script task using c#

```
Directory.getFiles( )
```

which is so much faster and store the array in a object variable.
the problem is, I do not know if is possible use that array variable in a data flow control as a souerce in order to join that paths with other collection which come from the database

thanks very much for your help

Comment: I think you mean SSIS, and not SSRS.

Comment: yes, you are right, silly me